# PHP SOAP is getting incomplete xml

Tags: php, soap

I am calling a webservice but sometimes i am getting incomplete xml response.
any one has any idea on this if i need to do any configuration setting in soap request?

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Can you post your request code ?

Comment: my requests contain credentials so i think i should not post.
but my request is 100% correct as i am requesting the api every 30 minutes per day.
and 2-3 time per day i am getting incomplete xml response and all other response comes correctly.
so i wanted to get help on if any soap setting needs to be done.
may be character length issue? but i am not sure.